# CSS selector for element that has content but no class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to be able to combine the selectors below, or use some other approach, to set a style for paragraphs that have content but no class.

```
p:not([class])   // selector for paras without a class attribute.
```

and

```
p:not(:empty)    // selector for empty paragraphs.
```

Have tried

```
p:not([class]):not(:empty)
```

but not working in Chrome.

Solution must be CSS only and cross-browser (modern only, no IE6 here!), and no JS or JQuery.

A bit more information as you may be wondering why I would want to do this - the use case is an input box which is content-editable. The idea is that the user must apply one of the allowed styles to their input and any that they miss has to be highlighted.  We had the no-class selector set but the richtext control we are using requires an empty para before user input, and so the highlight style appears when it should not. The richtext control is mandated, so I have to change the selector.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wrcccyd2/) what you want?

Comment: Apologies @user7393973 - I muddled the question. Have edited it. I actually need to style paragraphs that have content but no class.

Comment: Like this? `p:not([class]):not(:empty) { }`

Comment: That does work on Chrome, at least for me. Not sure why it wouldn't to you. Are you sure? Check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7pez3ryo/).

Comment: @user7393973 thanks on your prompting I looked deeper into the enforced blank para - to my surprise it contains a wayward <br>. My bad for not spotting, sorry to have wasted your time but thanks. I suspect a selector for 'no content except <br> would not be viable so I may have to take a different tack.  
If you put your suggestion in as an answer with the fiddle as an inline snippet I will mark you as the correct answer. The subject bears recording for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out,

1. `p:not([class]):not(:empty)` is correct.
2. However, your `p` element will match `:not(:empty)` if it contains whitespace, or any other element, including `br`.

If your rich text control enforces the leading `p` element, you may need to target that `p` separately with a different selector (one that's aware of your rich text control, at least), irrespective of the fact that it contains that wayward `br`.

Comment: Thanks and good suggestion but after sleeping on it my brain proposes that I may have to go to a scripted solution, annoyingly, not because of CSS selector weaknesses but because of other conditions and sequence of events.